# MVC4 : DropDownList works but not DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding, html.dropdownlistfor, html-select

I wanted to have [image: registration form] registration form for the admin side.

Right now my `DropDownList` works but I don't know how to get the value and write it to database(Sql server compact). Then again I thought may be using `DropDownList` would be better idea and could work but I get error. Here are my model

```
 public class UserModel
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email ID ")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 6)]
        [Display(Name = "Password ")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name ")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name ")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Address ")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public List<string> PossibleRights;

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Access Rights")]
        public string AccessRight { get; set; }

    }
```

I need to get the value from `dropdownlist` and set it to `Accessright`

my controller

```
 public List<SelectListItem> UserAccessRight()
        {
            var rights = new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "Full", Value = "0"},
                    new SelectListItem {Text = "Partial", Value = "1"}
                };
            return rights;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            var rights = UserAccessRight();
            ViewBag.right = rights;
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(Models.UserModel user)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var db = new DBaseEntities())
                {
                    var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();

                    var encrpPass = crypto.Compute(user.Password);

                    var sysUser = db.SystemUsers.Create();

                    sysUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                    sysUser.LastName = user.LastName;
                    sysUser.Address = user.Address;
                    sysUser.Email = user.Email;
                    sysUser.Password = encrpPass;
                    sysUser.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;

                    sysUser.AccessRight = user.AccessRight;


                    db.SystemUsers.Add(sysUser);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("","Login data is incorrect.");
            }
            return View();
        }

        private bool IsValid(string email, string password)
        {
            var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();

            bool isValid = false;
            using (var db = new DBaseEntities())
            {
                var user = db.SystemUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);

                if (user!= null)
                {
                    if (user.Password == crypto.Compute(password, user.PasswordSalt) )
                    {
                        isValid = true;
                    }
                }

            }

            return isValid;
        }
```

my view

```
 <h4>Signup Now!</h4>


            <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(u=> u.FirstName)</div>
            <div class="editor-field"> @Html.TextBoxFor(u=> u.FirstName)</div>   
            <br/>
            <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(u=> u.LastName)</div>
            <div class="editor-field"> @Html.TextBoxFor(u=> u.LastName)</div> 
            <br/>
            <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(u=> u.Address)</div>
            <div class="editor-field"> @Html.TextBoxFor(u=> u.Address)</div> 
            <br/>
            <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(u=> u.Email)</div>
            <div class="editor-field"> @Html.TextBoxFor(u=> u.Email)</div> 
            <br/>
            <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(u=> u.Password)</div>
            <div class="editor-field"> @Html.PasswordFor(u=> u.Password)</div> 
            <br/>
            <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(u=> u.AccessRight)</div>
            <div class="editor-field"> @Html.DropDownList("right")</div>

            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Register"/>
```

when I try to change the `@Html.DropDownList("right")` to 
`@Html.DropDownListFor((u=>u.AccessRight, new SelectList("right", "value", "text"),"--Select Right--")` I get error. Edit: error says "HttpException was unhandled by user code
Data Binding: 'System.Char' does not contain property with the name 'value'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have added it as edit in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AccessRight, new SelectList(ViewBag.right , "id", "Text "))
```

In model, Access right should contain a valid id that exist in **Viewbag.right** that is of Enumerable type.

Access right should contain a value that you want to show as selected in the Dropdown list

EDIT:-

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.AccessRight, new SelectList(ViewBag.right , "value", "Text "))
```

Name of the Datavalue field should be same to the list

Hope this helps

Comment: Still same error, now instead of value it says does not contain property with name "id"

Comment: so my AccessRight in model should not be string and should be enumerable type? Didn't get that part with AccessRight in model. Can you explain more may be?

Comment: Access right should contain a value that you want to show as selected in the Dropdown list. It should be of integer type. So it will check from your viewbag.right which is of enumerable type and show it as pre selected.

Comment: I wworked thanks alot, but now i get error on `db.SaveChanges();` part of my `Register` action. Says DbUpdateException was unhandled by user code. Any idea? or should i ask new question?

Comment: I think it is beacuse i'm trying to add user in post method and not in get method

Answer (score 0):

Try to change below code

from

```
<div class="editor-field"> @Html.DropDownList("right")</div>
```

to

```
<div class="editor-field"> @Html.DropDownList("AccessRight","Provide list of items here")</div>
```

On submit you will automatically get value in model for AccessRight.